# my android studio res layout xml files name showing duplicate

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, xml-namespaces

[Android studio xml file name problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yB02n.png)

my android studio res layout xml files name showing duplicate. Also my drawable file name showing two times. for example: main_activity.xmlmain_activity.xml. I also update my IDE but this weird thing is not gone.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Please try "invalidate caches and restart".
This should solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try Following Steps:

```
Clean project > Invalidate caches and restart > Rebuild Project
```